# When does a web worker create a new thread?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Does a web worker create a new thread when I create a new web worker by calling its constructor with a js file?

Or does a new thread get created every time that I call `postMessage`?

I basically need to know if I can generate new threads on an existing web worker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) goes, the "separate thread or process or equivalent construct" is created when you create the worker, and then it has an event loop like the main thread's event loop, which is where events like `message` get put.

Implementations are free to do what they want, though, provided it conforms to the semantics defined by the specification.

> I basically need to know if I can generate new threads on an existing web worker.

If you mean have a *single* worker that has more than one thread running *at the same time*, the only way to do that is to call `new Worker` more than once with the same script (which is a perfectly valid thing to do), which of course isn't a *single* worker with more than one thread, but rather two workers running the same code, each of which has one thread.

Comment: Thank you very much T.J, you answered my question. Have a great day!